# my form is acting insane since I moved it into my header

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't have a clue what is going on. This might not even be a javascript issue.

I decided that I wanted to allow my users to click on an icon in the navbar that opens a modal which contains a form that uses dropzone.js

There are other text inputs in the form. Since moving the form to the navbar, these inputs get random strings shown from existing database entries. So, for example, I click the icon on the navbar and the modal opens, the form shows for the `input#tag`: *choclate, vanilla, miami, lebron james*. Then if I reload the page and click it again, for `input#description`: *day at the beach*. Then if I reload it again, it might be `input#tag`: *detroit, rainbow* `input#description`: *white poodle*.

I am using Rails 4 and turbolinks 5.0.

This occurs regardless of whether I wrap my javascript in `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {});` or `$(document).ready(function () {});`

I stuck the `modal` code inside of `_header.html.erb`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default large-navbar navbar-fixed-top">...</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myuploadModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">...</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var dropzone3;
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  dropzone3 = new Dropzone('#dropform3', {
    maxFiles: 6,
    maxFilesize: 2.5,
    paramName: 'photo[picture]',
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-Token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    clickable: '.dz-default.dz-message.head',
    previewsContainer: '.dz-default.dz-message.head',
    thumbnailWidth: 120,
    thumbnailHeight: 120,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: false
  });
});
<script>
```

Adding the photos with dropzone.js works fine and the form still works.

The first input is simply: `<%= f.input :description, label: "Description:", placeholder: '' %>`

Comment: I think you should include your form and the controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many other questions involving rails and strange behavior, the cause is turbolinks malfunctioning.